# Firefox issue location.hash history.pushState NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE:

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have following code in my node application. I'm getting the above error (i.e. NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) for the below code. This error is specific to Firefox. I have no issue when working with Chrome.

```
 history.pushState({mainMenu: mainMenu, content: content, url:current, subMenu: subMenu, done:null}, "", location.hash);
```

As a result of this error the links are disabled (even links are clicked, the event is not triggering)

Comment: You need to provide a test case that demonstrates the problem. You have a whole bunch of variables that your code depends on which you haven't provided. I'd *guess* you are running into the [size limit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method), but I can't tell with what you've provided.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I found the answer. As you mentioned, it's about the size limit. For this specific case, I'm setting a fairly a large content for "content" value, and it exceeds default limit for Firefox.

Comment: I am running into this error as well, can you post what you did to solve it?  Especially if there was a way to increase the maximum size.